# Select option child component not reseting to key 0 on form submit with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a select option child component (called `Service`) for a form because I am loading the values with a JSON file. Also, I am using `event.preventDefault()` within my `handleSubmit()` event so that the `react-notifications` success message displays correctly, rather than disappearing right away because of the re-render.

This is causing my select option fields to maintain the value that was selected before the form was submitted. I need these to be reset to key 0, so that I have a "fresh" form.

I realize that `event.preventDefault()` prevents the form from naturally resetting, so I am clearing the state of my form elements after. This does not reset the select options though.

I tried removing `event.preventDefault()` and this allows the form to reset, but then my `react-notification` success message does not show.

I have tried placing the `react-notification` message in a different life cycle method (`componentDidUpdate()`), but I have not been successful as the success message does not show.

**Handle Submit**

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let formData = {
      name: this.state.name,
      phone: this.state.phone,
      email: this.state.email,
      service1: this.state.service1,
      service2: this.state.service2,
      service3: this.state.service3
    };

    fetch('/emails/requestform', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(
      this.createNotification('success'), 
      this.setState({name: ''}), 
      this.setState({phone: ''}), 
      this.setState({email: ''}), 
      this.setState({service1: ''}), 
      this.setState({service2: ''}), 
      this.setState({service3: ''})
    ).catch(error => console.log(`Error posting form: ` + error));
  }
```

**Service Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Service.css';

class Service extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmitForSelect = this.handleSubmitForSelect.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.props.onServicesChange(event.target.value);
  }

  handleSubmitForSelect(event) {
    this.setState(event.target.value = '');
  }

  render() {

    let services = this.props.state.services;
    let optionItems = services.map((service) => <option key={service.id} value={service.value}>{service.service}</option>);

    return (<div >
      <select className="select" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChange} onSubmit={this.handleSubmitForSelect}>
        {optionItems}
      </select>
    </div>)
  }
}

export default Service;
```

I expect the form to fully reset and the `react-notification` success message to still show. But at the moment it seems like only one or the other is possible.

Comment: Please could you create a codesandbox for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function argument to `then()` . Then your business logic goes inside the function

```
fetch('/emails/requestform', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify(formData),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
})
.then((resp) => resp.ok ? resp.json() : Promise.reject('Bad request status = '+ resp.status))
.then((data) => {
   // ^^^^^^^^^^ anonymous function argument

  // do something with response data here     

  this.createNotification('success');// <== semi colon not comma
  this.setState({
    name: '',
    phone: '',
    email: '',
    service1: '',
    service2: '',
    service3: ''
  });
}).catch((err)=> console.error(err))
```